# Overlapped Socket IO: WSAGetOverlappedResult Fails with 996 Errorcode

Tags: windows, networking, winsock

I am maintaining an old windows application and have an issue I have not been able to solve.  On new hardware, under various operating systems we have begun to see errors we have never seen where in the past it has been very stable.  It opens a UDP socket and configures it to broadcast UDP data.  It then steams data.  The code uses overlapped IO so it has a thread that waits around in a thread waiting for the overlapped IO events.   The socket is being opened like this:

```
// Create datagram socket
if (!SocketDgCreate(&m_SDGScan, pstAppState->szScannerIP, (short)nPort)){
    StatusMessage(MSG_ERR, "socket create failed on '%s' Port %u\r\n",
            pstAppState->szScannerIP, nPort);
    return false;
}

// Configure datagram socket for broadcast
int nSockOpt = TRUE;

if (setsockopt(m_SDGScan,
            SOL_SOCKET, 
            SO_BROADCAST, 
            (LPSTR)&nSockOpt, 
            sizeof(nSockOpt)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
    StatusMessage(MSG_ERR, "socket broadcast failed\r\n\t%s\r\n", 
        WSAGetLastErrorStr());
    return false;
}

// Allow the socket to be bound to an address already in use.
if (setsockopt(m_SDGScan, 
            SOL_SOCKET, 
            SO_REUSEADDR,
            (LPSTR)&nSockOpt, 
            sizeof(nSockOpt)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
    StatusMessage(MSG_ERR, "socket reuse address failed\r\n\t%s\r\n", 
        WSAGetLastErrorStr());
    return false;
}
```

On new hardware when we open the socket we get error 996 which is defined by Microsoft as this:

> Overlapped I/O event object not in signaled state. 
>       The application has tried to determine the status of an 
>       overlapped operation which is not yet completed. Applications 
>       that use WSAGetOverlappedResult (with the fWait flag set to 
>       FALSE) in a polling mode to determine when an overlapped 
>       operation has completed, get this error code until the 
>       operation is complete. Note that this error is returned by 
>       the operating system, so the error number may change in 
>       future releases of Windows.

The code that uses winsock to send the the data appears to do the right thing by processing the error code and verifying that it is not pending.

```
int nSendRet = WSASendTo(m_SDGScan, 
                    &m_astSendBuff[m_nSendCtr],
                    1,
                    &nNumSentImmed, 
                    0, 
                    (LPSOCKADDR)&m_scanDGDestAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR),
                    &m_scanDGOverlapped, 
                    NULL);          // Use event signal upon completion.

if (nSendRet == 0){
    // Sent immediately
    ++m_nSendCtr;
    if (m_nSendCtr == m_nNumQueued) {
        m_nSendCtr = m_nNumQueued = 0;
    }
}else if (nSendRet == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    // This could just be an overlap in progress state!
    int err = WSAGetLastError();
    if (err == WSA_IO_PENDING)  {
        // If the error indicates I/O pending then the Overlapped operation
        // was successfull and will complete later!
        SetEvent( m_hScanDGEvent );
    }
```

The code that actually triggers the error is in its own thread and looks like this:

```
UINT CXyz::Thread(LPVOID){

bool fEventSelect = true;
WSANETWORKEVENTS networkEvents;

DWORD dwOvlRslt = 0;
DWORD dwWaitVal;
DWORD dwNumSent;

// Turn on the XYZ datagram stuff.
// Load event into overlapped I/O structures
m_scanDGOverlapped.hEvent = m_hScanDGEvent;
ResetEvent(m_hScanDGEvent);

// Setup the events.
const int nNumEvents = 2;
HANDLE ahEvents[nNumEvents];
ahEvents[0] = m_hScanDGEvent;   // XYZ datagrams.
ahEvents[1] = m_hThreadStopEvent;

// Thread now alive!
m_fThreadAlive = true;

// Associate scan transmit event with socket, but no state yet (will be overridden)

if (WSAEventSelect(m_SDGScan, m_hScanDGEvent, FD_READ) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    StatusMessage(MSG_ERR, "XYZ DG event select failed 1 [%s]\r\n",
        WSAGetLastErrorStr());
}

// Thread loop processing...
bool bDone = false;
    dwWaitVal = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(nNumEvents, ahEvents, FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE);

    // Acq buffer done or delay timer expired
    switch (dwWaitVal)
    {
    case WAIT_FAILED:               // Bad,
        StatusMessage(MSG_ERR, "XYZ thread aborting [%d]\r\n", GetLastError());
        bDone = true;
        break;

    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:             // XYZ datagrams.
        // Clears internal records and resets event object

        // Clears internal records and resets event object
        if (WSAEnumNetworkEvents(m_SDGScan, m_hScanDGEvent, &networkEvents) ==
                SOCKET_ERROR){
            StatusMessage(MSG_ERR, "XYZ WSAEnumNetworkEvents() failed [%s]\r\n",
                    WSAGetLastErrorStr());
            bDone = true;
        }else if (!WSAGetOverlappedResult(
                            m_SDGScan,
                            &m_scanDGOverlapped,
                            &dwNumSent,
                            FALSE,
                            &dwOvlRslt)){
            // Get status of last send
            StatusMessage(MSG_ERR, "WSAGetOverlappedResult() failed [%s]\r\n",WSAGetLastErrorStr());
           }else{
               // Handle next packet code omitted
           }

    case (WAIT_OBJECT_0+1):         // Shutdown.
        bDone = true;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Well, the error code says that you call WSAGetOverlappedResult() at the wrong time.  Yet you posted a snippet that makes it completely unguessable when that call is made.

Answer (score 2):

Error code 996 is `WSA_IO_INCOMPLETE`, which as you noted is documented as follows:

> The application has tried to determine the status of an overlapped operation **which is not yet completed**. Applications that use `WSAGetOverlappedResult` (**with the `fWait` flag set to FALSE**) in a polling mode to determine when an overlapped operation has completed, get this error code **until the operation is complete**.

You are, in fact, setting the `fWait` parameter to FALSE, so the error is perfectly normal behavior.  Since you are polling the state, you will have to call `WSAGetOverlappedResult()` in a loop until it stops reporting `WSA_IO_INCOMPLETE`.

Otherwise, set the `fWait` parameter to TRUE instead and let it block the calling thread until the I/O operation is complete.

Comment: Remy: I missed a couple of lines on the cut and paste in an effort to be concise.  (I added them) The WSAGetOverlappedResult call that processes that error code is in a thread waiting for status codes of the socket writes. It isn't clear to me why we should be notified of a pending call in this situation, I think I should not expect a call pending result from something that should be sending status *after* completion.

Comment: How many handles are you passing to `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx()`? What types of handles are you putting into `ahEvents`? `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx()` returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0` only for the first handle in the array, it returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0+1` for the second handle, and so on. Is `m_hScanDGEvent` the first handle in `ahEvents`?

Comment: But more importantly, **why are you signaling `m_hScanDGEvent` manually** when `WSASendTo()` is pending? Assuming `m_hScanDGEvent` is the event that is associated with `m_scanDGOverlapped` then DO NOT signal it manually! `WSASendTo()` will reset it upon pending and then it will be signaled automatically when the send is actually complete, let the OS manage the signaling, not you.

Comment: This code is 10 years old and the original author is gone and has been processing data without fail over that time. I am not sure of the decisions that went into the design. Recent hardware/driver updates have exposed this behavior. There are two events being waited on, the data being sent and the thread being terminated. The WAIT_OBJECT_0+1 sets a flag that allows the thread to shut down gracefully. The way I read the code is that the result of the send is available to be read but when it is read it says it is pending. I would think with overlapped IO this should never happen.  -Merci

Answer (score 0):

I was working with serial communication in flutter and this error appeared.
After lot of research I found out that the reason of this error was I was sending read request and my timeout/waiting for response time was infinite or too long and before completing the first request or before getting the response I was sending another read request that's why this error came.